# Karate Analytics

Tags: java, adobe, analytics, karate

My project is required to do ui testing and to track Adobe Analytics. I know that there are options with Java libraries. But I'm willing to use Karate and combine it with Adobe Analytics. Any suggestions?

Comment: I recommend looking at these other answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59792468/143475 https://stackoverflow.com/a/54527955/143475